# Return values in OneToOneField as string - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a OneToOneField (pointing to a second model) and I want to return values inside the variables of that second model.

This one is the second model:

```
class EstablishmentTable(models.Model): #Tabla de establecimientos

    #id for the 'pk as we have not declare any
    etmail = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    etpass = models.CharField(max_length=1024) #SHA-1024, SHA-512. SHA-256
    etname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    etnumqueue = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: "+self.etname+" mail: "+self.pk
```

This one the first model:

```
class QueueTable(models.Model): #Tabla de colas

    #id for the 'pk as we have not declare any
    qtname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    qtestablishment = models.OneToOneField(EstablishmentTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    qtnumstate = models.IntegerField()
    qtdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: "+self.qtestablishment+" mail: "+self.pk
```

How can I do to access to the **qtestablishment** variables? If I write 
`return "name: "+self.qtestablishment+" mail: "+self.pk` It returns:

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "EstablishmentTable") to str`

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the name of the `self.qtestablishment`, since you made this Null-able however, you need to guard against a `None`:

```
class QueueTable(models.Model): #Tabla de colas
    qtname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    qtestablishment = models.OneToOneField(EstablishmentTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    qtnumstate = models.IntegerField()
    qtdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.qtestablishment is None:
            return …  # return something in case qtestablishment is None
        return 'name: {} mail: {}'.format(self.qtestablishment.etname, self.pk)
```

or you can call `str(..)` on the `self.qtestablishment` object, that will thus return the result of the `__str__` method you defined on the `EstablishmentTable`. We can for example do that with `.format(…)`:

```
class QueueTable(models.Model): #Tabla de colas
    qtname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    qtestablishment = models.OneToOneField(EstablishmentTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    qtnumstate = models.IntegerField()
    qtdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'name: {} mail: {}'.format(self.qtestablishment, self.pk)
```

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Table` suffix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I was also missing the str conversion of the self.pk in the EstablishmentTable `return "name: "+self.etname+" pk: "+str(self.pk)`. Thank you for the note as well, the suffix Table is just for me to clarify the equivalence of a model to a "database table".  Im new with django jeje.